# Meteor says that protocol in MAIL_URL must be 'smtp' while it is smtp

Tags: email, meteor, smtp, gmail

Meteor gives me this exception:

> Exception while invoking method 'membershipRequest.reject' Error: Email protocol in $MAIL_URL (fakehisab%40gmail.com:Password@smtp.gmail.com:587) must be 'smtp' or 'smtps'

I tried port `465` too, but got the same result.

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The URL in your error description suggests otherwise. It has no protocol.

Comment: oh, thanks. @MasterAM